How to Assign Sequential Names to EC2 Instances in AWS Auto-Scaling Group?
Question:
Hi,
I'm using AWS Auto Scaling Groups (ASG) to manage my EC2 instances. Currently, all instances get the same name, but I need each instance to have a unique, sequential name like Instance-1, Instance-2, etc.
Current Setup:

AWS Auto Scaling launches and manages EC2 instances.

Instances receive the same name from the launch configuration.


Requirement:

Unique, sequential instance names.

Challenges:

AWS ASG doesn't support sequential naming natively.

Need a reliable method to dynamically assign and maintain these names.


Attempts So Far:

Tagging instances post-launch using AWS CLI scripts.

Considering AWS Lambda with CloudWatch Events for lifecycle hooks but unsure about managing the sequence.


Questions:

Best practices for assigning sequential names in ASG?

How to implement a reliable solution for this?

Are there AWS services to simplify this process?

Any example implementations or guides?


Thanks for your help!

See: Individualize user-data in an AWS autoscaling group - Stack Overflow

Is there a particular reason why you need sequential names as opposed to a unique ID? Can you tell us more about your use-case? What happens if there are instances 1, 2 and 3 but then Auto Scaling terminates instance 2 -- what should be the next number used? Would it be 4 or 2?
